# Infinite graph without infinite clique or infinite independent set

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there an infinite graph $G=(V,E)$ such that $G$ neither has an infinite clique, nor an infinite independent set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not exist such a graph.  Take the infinite version of ramsey's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem) and use the special case with 2 colors (edge or non-edge) and you are coloring the 2-subsets of the vertices (for a simple graph).  The result is that you always have an infinite monochromatic subgraph.